# Javascript Array of Instances of a class

Tags: javascript, class, object

In JS, I have a class called `player` which is:

```
class player {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and I have two instances of it, called `PL1` and `PL2`:

```
const PL1 = new player ('pl1name');
const PL2 = new player ('pl2name');
```

I also have an array called `PLAYERS`:

```
let PLAYERS = [];
```

now, the question is how can I create an array with all of the instances of the class `player`?

I know I can manually do this with `PLAYERS.push(PL`**n**`)`; but I'm looking for a way to do this somehow automatically. Is there a built-in function? Should I use a loop?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could create a class that is a container class for the players. This will allow the container to create players and manage them. The `Players` class can expose an interface making it easy to interact with the players individually or as a whole. Something like this might be a good start and could be filled out with more functionality or different organisation:

```js
// An individual player. Holds properties and behaviour for one player
class Player {
  constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
  play() {
    console.log(this.name, "plays")
  }
}

// Class that holds a collection of players and properties and functions for the group
class Players {
  constructor(){
    this.players = []
  }
  // create a new player and save it in the collection
  newPlayer(name){
    let p = new Player(name)
    this.players.push(p)
    return p
  }
  get allPlayers(){
    return this.players
  }
  // this could include summary stats like average score, etc. For simplicity, just the count for now
  get numberOfPlayers(){
      return this.players.length
  }
}

let league = new Players()
league.newPlayer("Mark")
league.newPlayer("Roger")

// list all the players
console.log(league.numberOfPlayers + " Players)
console.log(league.allPlayers)


// make them do something
league.allPlayers.forEach(player => player.play())
```

Comment: Why did you use return on newPlayer?

Comment: Hey @Shahriar good catch, I wanted to return the player there, but returned the result of `push` instead -- I edited it to fix that. This will let you use `let aPlayer = league.newPlayer("SomePlayer")` and get a reference to the new player, which can be convenient.

Comment: Now it makes sense @MarkMeyer :) I really enjoyed your approach to this problem (the whole question).

Comment: After 3 years, I now understand JS and your answer :D Marked it as the accepted!

Answer (score 5):

To initialize an Array with a static amount of `Player` objects, you could call `new Player()` in the array:

```
const players = [new Player('name1'), new Player('name2'), new Player('name3')];
```

You could also dynamically create your player list using a loop:

```
const playerNames = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
let players = [];
playerNames.forEach((playerName) => players.push(new Player(playerName)));
```

Comment: Nice way. But what if I have two parameters for creating a new `player`? Will the syntax be `const playerDetail = [('param1, param2'), ...]`?

Comment: yea you could do `[new Player('param1', 'param2')]`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just want to write the data to the array.
So you need a two dimensional array.

Next you can write or read the values to and from the array.

```
class player {
constructor(name, val, ...) {
    this.name = name;
    this.val = val; // ....
}

toarr()
{
arr=[];
arr[0] = this.name;
arr[1] = this.val; //etcetera
return arr;
}

fromarr(arr){
this.name = arr[0];
this.val = arr[1]
...
}   
}
```

actually you need just one instance of player, and reset the values everytime to access or create other players.

```
reset( name, val){
this.name = name;
this.val = val; // ....}
```

so, code equal to the constructor.

eventually the array of all players will look somewhat like this:

```
players = [];
current_player = new player (name, val);
players[0] = current_player.toarr();
current_player.reset(name1, val1);
players[1] = current_player.toarr();
```

or

```
current_player.fromarr[24];
```

(note you could also write code like current_player.byname(name))

If you want to compare two players, or all players, you just need two instances of player.

When writing to a two dimensional array, you can use  named values. I like it this way.

```
const NAME = 0;
const VAL = 1;
etcetera
```

You can easily add a value to the array, by adding a val2 (weight, length, income, likes) You can even add names_of_children; an array within the 2 dimensional array. But this might cause some problems.

To compare players, or to sort players, you could also just access the array.

If you write all code in a seperated file, and this file is only loaded if you access and manipulate data of the players, you do not have to make a class of het array, it could as well be a module.

```
if (we_use_the_players_array === true) {do load the players.js file}
```

refreshing the whole page, so other  ... .js files are not used

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment your answer as of now so here's an addition:

```
class player {
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
        PLAYERS.push(this);
    }
}
```

PLEASE: be aware there's a whole lot of awful practices in this few lines, you shouldn't tie a constructor to a variable that may or may not be initialized somewhere else, meddling with the constructor with whatever external is plain awful. Also classes are usually title-cased.

Plus as a side note, while it's real that you can change consts properties while maintaining the reference, so you *can* push objects in an array that's declared as const, it really doesn't add up as self-documenting code, so, if you are going to modify this array, just declare it with "let" from the start.

Comment: Thank you for your awareness. I changed Const to Let.

Comment: You mean not to write codes more than object properties inside constructor?

Comment: Constructors should only relate to what they are "constructing" in effects, so when you tie in a variable that may or may not be related you are basically discarding a set of functionalities, like being able to export this class without the PLAYERS constant. Also as a matter of good practises code should be as declarative as possible (means you should be able to understand what code is doing without uncovering the implementation), and when you instantiate an object you want to instantiate an object, not push the object in an unrelated array. So yes, avoid unrelated side-effects in constructors

Answer (score 0):

You can push every instance into a static array of the class as part of your constructor method. (In the most basic form this could look something like the code below)

This answer explains it a bit more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71696802/19529102

The linked answer also provides an improvement which fixes the flaw, that in this basic version the array is directly exposed/returned

```js
class Player {

    static all = [];

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        Player.all.push(this);
    }
}

const PL1 = new Player("pl1name");
const PL2 = new Player("pl2name");

console.log(Player.all);
console.log(PL1.all); //undefined; instance of Player does not inherit all

const PL3 = new Player("pl3name");

console.log(Player.all);
```