# How to return an array of objects from a method in the same class javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object

I am new to javascript. I want a class method to return an array of objects instantiated by the same class. How to do that?

Currently,Basically the following is the general structure my code in question.

```
class myClass{
   constructor(name,password,emailid,id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.emailid = emailid;
    this.id = id;
  }

  asyncMethod = async()=> {
     //method returns array of objects of same class
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

On Class instantiation (`constructor` init), push the current instance to a class's [**static** Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).
**Retrieve all your instances** by either using `userInstance.getInstances()` (← this is bad practice! Read further) or `User.instances`

```js
class User {

  static instances = [];

  constructor(name, password, emailid, id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.emailid = emailid;
    this.id = id;
    User.instances.push(this); // Push instance into static Class's property
  }

  getInstances() {
    return User.instances; // Return array of instances of same Class
  }
}

const A = new User("Cada", "123", "c@c.c", 1);
const B = new User("Roko", "234", "r@r.r", 2);
const C = new User("John", "345", "j@j.j", 3);

console.log(A.name, B.name, C.name); // "Cada", "Roko", "John"
console.log(A.getInstances());  // [User, User, User]
console.log(myClass.instances); // [User, User, User]
```

Closely related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61014433/383904

And I could not explain the `static` keyword better than [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static):

> Neither static methods nor static properties can be called on instances of the class. Instead, **they're called on the class itself**. *(*ac: `myClass.instances` in the above demo)*
> Static methods are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects, whereas static properties are useful for caches, fixed-configuration, or **any other data you don't need to be replicated across instances**.

---

It's usually a **bad practice to expose internals** of a Class to an Instance.
For Example, a *User* instance should not be able to inherit from its Class constructor the entire list of Users.
Here's a slight variant that uses **Static Private** `#` and Class **Getters** `get`:

```js
class User {

  static #_instances = []; // Static and private

  constructor(userData) {
    Object.assign(this, userData);
    User.#_instances.push(this);
  }

  static get instances() { // Static to Class
    return [...User.#_instances]; // exposes private (as immutable)
  }
}

const A = new User({name:"Cada", password:"123", emailid:"c@c.c", id:1});
const B = new User({name:"Roko", password:"234", emailid:"r@r.r", id:2});

console.log(A.name, B.name); // "Cada", "Roko",

console.log(A.instances);            // undefined 
console.log(User.instances);         // [User, User] 

User.instances.push({name:"EVIL!"}); //   
console.log(User.instances);         // [User, User]
```

Comment: Wasn't it better to not expose/return the instance array directly but instead a shallow copy of it ... `get instances() { return Array.from(User.#_instances); }`? Thus the truth about the instance' storage is always with `User.#_instances` which can not be manipulated as it still can be done with the above implementation.

Comment: @PeterSeliger You mean `return [...User.#_instances]` ;) Great concerning question and a valid notice! I believe that it's implementation (business-logic) related. Whatever you return the containing objects are still a pointer to memory. Therefore If one is obsolete, the other is too.

Comment: _"... the containing objects are still a pointer to memory"_ ... of cause, they have to be. It is not the code's responsibility to control/protect each `User` instance. But the code should protect the state of the private static `#_instances` array itself. Thus, this array's reference should not be exposed into public in order to not get mutated (pushing into it ... slicing, popping, shifting from it) by outside processes.

Comment: @PeterSeliger added your valid points to the answer.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you for the answer. I don't want all the instances of the object. Basically what i want is 

```

const A = new User({name:"Cada", password:"123", emailid:"c@c.c", id:1});
const B = new User({name:"Roko", password:"234", emailid:"r@r.r", id:2});

```

this part would be called by the method. i.e. the method would call another function which will give a list of records with same name, email, id and those have to be intantiated and returned as an object array of the same class. Some kind of recursion.

Is it possible?